# SQL запрос, SUM() AVG() разных столбцов в одном запросе,по разным количеством записей

Tags: sql, sql-server, выборка

исходная таблица:

```
Date                            Temperature    NumMesurements
2018-11-04 07:00:00.000          21,1           1
2018-11-04 08:00:00.000          21,2           3
2018-11-04 09:00:00.000          21,4           2
2018-11-04 10:00:00.000          21,6           4
2018-11-04 11:00:00.000          21,2           5  
2018-11-04 12:00:00.000          21,2           1 
2018-11-04 13:00:00.000          21,2           1
```

Как получить результат за диапазон времени(например с 8 до 12) по 2 часа чтобы выглядело:

```
конец двухчасовки        средняя_температура  количество измерений
2018-11-04 10:00:00.000          21,3                5
2018-11-04 12:00:00.000          21,4                9
```

Базу использую MS Sql server.

Comment: `group by cast(date as date), datepart(hour, date)/2`

Comment: а какая у Вас база данных?

Comment: @Mike Спасибо то что надо

Comment: @Yaroslav Базу использую MS Sql server.

Comment: @Mike . Подскажите пожалуйста , если указывать  диапазон времени с 8-12 с группировкой предложенной вами в результате получается
     2018-11-04 10:00:00.000          21,3                5
     2018-11-04 12:00:00.000          21,4                9
но если указать диапазон с 9-13 получается
     2018-11-04 09:00:00.000          21,4           2
     2018-11-04 10:00:00.000          21,3           5
     2018-11-04 12:00:00.000          21,4           9
     2018-11-04 13:00:00.000          21,2           1 

как правильно адаптировать чтобы начало времени не играло роли?

Comment: не понял вопрос, но если что, часы можно корректировать что бы при делении получалась желаемая разбивка. Прибавляя к ним некую величину. Например остаток от деления часов из начала диапазона поиска на 2 (что бы учесть его нечетность)

Comment: @Mike , если правильно понял, группировку переделал на 
cast(date as date), DATEPART(hour,DATEADD(hour,-1,date))/2  (чтобы правильно  группировалось если начало часа нечетное), так отображает верно, вы так советовали?

Comment: слишком сложно :) `(datepart(hour, date)+1)/2` причем именно + что бы отрицательного числа не было.

Comment: @Mike Спасибо за ответ